# How do I create a dictionary with a date in a Pandas Pivot Table Query?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that looks like this:-
[image]

I need to create a Pandas Pivot Table that will output a table like this:

[image]

That is it sums all dates less than 01-Oct-20 as Overdue and then sums all dates from 01-Oct-20 onwards normally.

The code below is what I have figured out so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# creating a data frame 
df = pd.read_csv("CSVData2.csv") 

table = pd.pivot_table(data=df,index=['Code'], columns=['Process Month'], values = ['Number'], aggfunc=sum)
print(table)
```

Comment: Why don't we just combine your `pivot_table` with the dataframe that calculated the expiry totals

Comment: @r-beginners I receive the data in a CSV file then I need to process it.

Comment: After reading the csv file and turning it into a data frame, why not calculate the expiry date and then run your pivot table and join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could work for you?

```
# Recreating your dataframe in code
df = pd.DataFrame({'Code':'A1 P2 B3 B3 C4 A1 B3 A1 A1'.split(' '),
                  'Branch':'UW2 RQ2 UW2 UW2 X01 X01 DN9 PE7 PE7'.split(' '),
                  'Process Month':'01-Oct-20 01-Nov-20 01-Sep-20 01-Sep-20 01-Aug-20 01-Oct-20 01-Sep-20 01-Dec-20 01-Sep-20'.split(' '),
                  'Number':[1]*9})

#Change string to datetime dtype
df['Process Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Process Month'])

# Create mask to defined 'Overdue'    
m = df['Process Month'] < '01-Oct-20'

# Output Process Month back as string
df['Process Month'] = df['Process Month'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')

# Overwriting Process Month with 'OverDue' per mask above
df.loc[m, 'Process Month'] = 'OverDue'

# Creating a crosstab with totals
df_out = pd.crosstab(df['Code'], df['Process Month'], margins=True, margins_name='Total')

df_out.drop('Total', axis=1) #Don't need row Totals column
```

Output:

```
Process Month  01-Dec-2020  01-Nov-2020  01-Oct-2020  OverDue
Code                                                         
A1                       1            0            2        1
B3                       0            0            0        3
C4                       0            0            0        1
P2                       0            1            0        0
Total                    1            1            2        5
```

Comment: It's easier to update the date as it expires. You're almost at 100k to go.

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks.   Be safe and stay healthy!

Comment: @Scott Boston Thanks for your time and answer.  I am a Python beginner trying to automate stuff I do. Is it possible to do this without the split of the codes and branches there are 110 codes and about 72 branches. All of which change regularly.

Comment: @Anthony The first statement is just to create your input dataframe.  You don't need this statement if you getting the input dataframe from somewhere else. I just used split to save on typing.  Ideally, you should create this type of code in your question to give the SO community as much input and ability to create a useful solution for you.